# Semidependent Actions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I am looking for a Haskell design to compose a chain of monadic actions (usually IO) in a manner, that later actions are dependent on previous ones but in some cases can be executed before they have finished.

The solution I came up with so far is:

```
type Future m a = m (m a)
```

Read: a monadic action, which starts some process and returns an action which will return the result of that process (possibly by waiting for this process to finish).

So in some chain `a >>= b >>= c` b gets an action returning a’s result. If b evaluates this action it waits for a to finish, otherwise it will be run in parallel. That also means that if some action does not require the result of the previous one as argument, it does not depend on it by definition, so the dependencies are explicit.

Some example code:

```
date :: Future IO String   -- long process to find out the date
date = do
    print "attempting to get date"  -- will usually start some thread or process to compute the date
    return (print "today")  -- will wait for this thread or process and return the computed date

main = do
    d <- date   -- starts recieving the date
    print "foo" -- some other process
    d >>= print -- waits until the date has been computed and prints it out
```

Output:

```
"attempting to get date"
"foo"
"today"
```

There is a problem through: if an action decides to wait for the previous one it will always be dependent on all the others before (in my case). But in the example above if c decides to wait for b but b did not decide to wait for a, c may start before a has finished, which should not happen.

As a solution I wrote another combining operator:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => Future m a -> (m a -> Future m b) -> Future m b
a >=> f = do
    r1 <- a
    r2 <- f r1
    return (r1 >> r2)
```

So this will combine the “wait actions” and `a >=> b >=> c` will work just fine, if c waits for b this wait action will also wait for a.
However there is another problem with this approach (apart from that you need to remember to use >=> instead of >>=): the wait actions may be evaluated many times.
If b waits for a and c waits for b the wait for b will be connected to the wait for a nevertheless and thus the wait for a will be executed twice.

The actual problem is in >=>: `f r1` may evaluate r1 in wich case it does not need to be sequenced with r2 in the return statement (as it already was executed and thus a has finished). But it also might not, I cannot know.

So what I basically want is exactly this but without the possibility to run the wait actions several times. Unfortunately I am not very experienced in functional design.

So I hope you can enlighten me in some way how to augment or change my design or point me to a different, more flexible approach.

**Edit** According to the answers so far I like to give some more clarification about what I actually want:

I do not want to defer (or even skip) the execution of actions, neither do I require threads or similar parallelism features. Actually I am calling external processes. An example would be

```
backup :: Future IO ExitCode
backup = do
    pid <- startProcess "backup"
    return (waitForProcessAndGetExitCode pid)
```

When I now chain actions like `backup >=> otherAction`, otherAction can run while the backup is running (which saves much time overall). But otherAction may require the backup to be completed, in which case it can use its parameter to wait for the backup and to check whether it was successful. Either way the backup has to be executed.

I am now looking for a nice general solution, ideally not tied to the IO monad.

**Update** I found a solution that worked for me. I described it in a seperate answer below.

Comment: You might want to choose a different name for your new combinator, [because `>=>` is already taken](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).

Comment: Even though you do not require parallel execution, threads (as mentioned in some answers) may be a good solution.  Threads in Haskell are fairly easy to use.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that for sufficiently lazy monads, (e.g. the lazy State monad), you don't need to do anything to get the semantics you want.

Comment: @JohnL That sounds very interesting. I was wondering whether Haskell’s lazyness would help me and I was not able to come up with something working. Does this also work with my constrain, that if in `a >>= b >>= c` c waits for b it also waits for a automatically?

Comment: @ipsec: I don't know if this is what John L was thinking, but you might want to investigate `MonadFix` (and GHC's recursive `do`notation extension)

Comment: You might find inspiration in the [Orc library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/orc-1.2.1.1), which can be used to coordinate external processes.  In particular, it has a combinator `eagerly`, which spawns an action and returns a handle that can be used to wait for the action to terminate.

Comment: @ipsec - yes it would help with your constraint of everything waiting automatically.  However it probably isn't a sufficient solution, because some monads aren't sufficiently lazy for this to work.  Notably `IO` isn't, although it can be made to be so if you can use the proper unsafe functions.  `MonadFix`, I think, will only help indirectly (again, there's no `MonadFix` instance for IO).

Comment: Incidentally, upon further reflection I very highly doubt that a general solution is possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you actually wanted this signature:

```
(>>=) :: Future m a -> (a -> Future m b) -> Future m b
```

Here's how you implement what you want:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans

newtype Future m a = Future { runFuture :: m (m a) }

instance (Monad m) => Monad (Future m) where
    return = Future . return . return
    m >>= f = Future $ do
        fut1 <- runFuture m
        return $ join $ join $ liftM (runFuture . f) fut1

instance MonadTrans Future where
    lift = Future . liftM return
```

In other words, `Future` is a monad transformer, and nothing about its implementation is specialized to the `IO` monad.  However, the following example will show how you use it in conjunction with the `IO` monad to chain futures:

```
parallel :: IO a -> Future IO a
parallel m = Future $ do
    v <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO $ m >>= putMVar v
    return $ takeMVar v

future1 = parallel $ do
    threadDelay 1000000
    putStrLn "Hello, World" 
    return 1
future2 n = parallel $ do
    threadDelay 1000000
    print n
    return 2
future3 = future1 >>= future2

main = do
    f <- runFuture future3
    putStrLn "I'm waiting..."
    r <- f
    print r
```

I haven't yet proven that it satisfies the monad laws or the monad transformer laws, but I will try to do that and I will update you on whether or not it checks out.  Until then, there might be a misplaced `join` somewhere in there.

Edit: Nope!  Not even close.  It definitely does not satisfy the monad laws.  I don't know if I was close or not, but just assume this answer is incorrect for now.  However, I'm kind of intrigued now and wonder if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one possibility is to refuse to even run `f` until its output is demanded:

```
mma >=> fab = return $ do
    ma <- mma
    b  <- fab ma
    b
```

Depending on just what you want, it may be important to run `mma` first:

```
mma >=> fab = do
    ma <- mma
    return $ do
        b <- fab ma
        b
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I need to start all processes in my use case, even when their results are never used. I’m just trying to save time by not waiting for processes I don’t need to know about at the moment.

Comment: @ipsec - I was going to respond with a different approach, but are you familiar with the threads package? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads.  It might work for you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the restriction that you have a `MonadIO` instance for `m`, you can do something like this (from memory, untested):

```
share :: IO a -> IO (IO a)
share m = do
    ref <- newIORef Nothing
    let reader = do
          cached <- readIORef ref
          case cached of
            Just a -> return a
            Nothing -> m >>= \a -> writeIORef ref (Just a) >> return a
    return reader
```

You can change this to `share2 :: IO a -> IO a` by wrapping the IORef creation in `unsafePerformIO`, and it's simple to generalize to any `MonadIO` instance.

But, depending on your problem, you might be better off with something like `threads` or `IVar`.

Comment: Caching the result would be a solution and would certainly work in my use case. However I am wondering whether a more general solution over arbitrary monads would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

For cases, when you want to spark some threads and at some moment to collect results, check http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-SampleVar.html and http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html#g:2 , as they seems relevant

For cases, when you need execute actions on demand, you may find this code useful
Not checked in GHC but should work after typos fixed

```
module Promise (SuspendedAction, createSuspendedAction, getValueFromSuspendedAction)
import Data.IORef

data Promise a = Suspended (IO a) | Done a

data SuspendedAction = SA (IORef (Promise a))

createSuspendedAction :: m a -> m (SuspendedAction a)
createSuspendedAction act = newIORef (Suspended act)

readSuspendedAction :: SuspendedAction a -> m a
readSuspendedAction (SA ref) = readIORef ref >>= \suspended -> case suspended of
  Done a -> return a
  Suspended sact -> sact >>= \rv -> writeIORef ref (Done rv) >> return rv
```

BTW, check hackage carefully, there was package which allow to execute IO actions lazily while respecting their order.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself, albeit not entirely for the problem I have postet.

I realized that I have to know somehow beforehand, whether or not an action is dependant from the one before. I tried various approaches and evenually came up with something I am going to describe now.
My solution allows to write code like

```
a :: Process IO x ()
a = independant $ do
    print "start a"
    return $ print "end a"

b :: Process IO x Int
b = independant $ do
    print "start b"
    return $ print "end b" >> return 0

c :: Process IO Int ()
c = dependant $ \x -> do
    print $ "start c with " ++ show x
    return $  print ("end c, started with " ++ show x)

chain = a >~ b >~ c
main = exec chain

-- outputs:
"start a" "start b" "end a" "end b" "start c with 0" "end c, started with 0"
```

(more examples below)

I used the following types

```
type Future m a = m (m a)
type Action m a b = a -> Future m b
type Process m a b = forall c. Action m c a -> Action m c b  -- will need -XRank2Types
```

with the following primitives:

```
-- sequences f after g, f is dependant of g and gets its result
-- dependant :: Monad m => Action m a b -> Action m c a -> Action c b
dependant :: Monad m => Action m a b -> Process m a b
dependant f g a = join (g a) >>= f

-- sequences f after g, f is independant of g
independant :: Monad m => Future m a -> Process m b a
independant f g a = do
    w1 <- g a
    w2 <- f
    return (w1 >> w2)

-- concenation of processes
(>~) = flip (.)
```

This approach allows other primitives for easier handling as well, for instance:

```
-- lifts a pure function into an action
pureA :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> Action m a b
pureA f a = return . return $ f a

-- makes an action wich always returns the same result
constA :: Monad m => b -> Action m a b
constA = pureA . const

-- no operation action
nop :: Monad m => Action m a ()
nop = constA ()

-- puts a sequence point
wait :: Monad m => Process m a a
wait = dependant $ pureA id

-- modify its result with a pure function
modify :: (Monad m, Functor m) => (a -> b) -> Process m a b
modify f act a = do
    x <- act a
    return (fmap f x)

-- makes a process, wich always returns the same result
constP :: (Monad m, Functor m) => b -> Process m a b
constP = modify . const
```

And finally a function to run a process:

```
-- executes a process
exec :: Monad m => Process m () b -> m b
exec p = join $ p nop undefined
```

So a few a little more complex examples:

```
simleI :: String -> a -> Process IO b a
simpleI name r = independant $ do
    print ("start " ++ name)
    return $ print ("end " ++ name) >> return r

simpleD :: (Show a, Show b) => String -> (a -> b) -> Process IO a b
simpleD name f = dependant $ \a -> do
    print ("start " ++ name ++ " with " ++ show a)
    let r = f a
    return $ print ("end " ++ name ++ " with " ++ show r ++ " (started with " ++ show a ++ ")") >> return r

a = simpleI "a" ()
b = simpleI "b" 42
c = simpleD "c" (+1)
d = simpleI "d" ()

chain1 = a >~ b >~ c >~ d       -- == d . c . b . a
chain2 = a >~ wait >~ b >~ c >~ d
chain3 = a >~ b >~ modify (+1) >~ c >~ d

main = do
    exec chain1
    print "---"
    exec chain2
    print "---"
    exec chain3
```

Output:

```
"start a"
"start b"
"end a"
"end b"
"start c with 42"
"start d"
"end c with 43 (started with 42)"
"end d"
"---"
"start a"
"end a"
"start b"
"end b"
"start c with 42"
"start d"
"end c with 43 (started with 42)"
"end d"
"---"
"start a"
"start b"
"end a"
"end b"
"start c with 43"
"start d"
"end c with 44 (started with 43)"
"end d"
```

This is almost exactly what I want.

I am a little curious how to classify Action and Process. They are not monads. They may be Arrows, but I am too unfamiliar with Arrows to tell. Process may be an Applicative with fmap = modify and pure = const . constA oder something like that.

Please feel free to comment anything that comes in your mind about my approach, especially how to extend or simplify it.